# Using multiple colormaps on same axis with ezsurf

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I'm trying to plot several symbolic functions in the same subplot. Using `ezsurf` makes it easy to plot symbolic functions, but it doesn't seem to be very configurable.

I can't colour the individual graphs (see the figure below). They all automatically take the normal `jet` colourmap.  How can they use different colormaps?

[image: Multiple graphs, all using the same colour scheme]

**edit**: Here's the new code I'm running using `freezeColors` as suggested in the answer:

```
subplot(2,2,4)
for i = 1:numClasses
    f(i) = M_k(i)/sum(M_k);
    freezeColors
    hold on
    ezsurfc(x,y,f(i), [0 max(mean(1:numClasses))*2 0 max(mean(1:numClasses))*2],l)
    switch i
        case 1
            colormap(copper)
        case 2
            colormap(bone)
        case 3
            colormap(spring)
        case 4
            colormap(hsv)
        otherwise
            colormap(jet)
    end
    hold off
    unfreezeColors
    alpha(0.7)
end
```

And this produces the image shown below:

[image: Too much bone!]

Why are the colormaps still not different?

Comment: How do you want them colored?  You can just run `colormap(...)` after `ezsurf` to recolor the surface.

Comment: I can't do that easily – it ends up recoloring other subplots as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since changing the color map of one `axes` in a figure via `colormap` changes it for all `axes` in the figure, you need to use a workaround to get different color maps in your individual subplots.  The MathWorks article ["Using multiple colormaps in a single figure"](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/24/using-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure/) lists three methods:

1. [Combine multiple colormaps into one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2009a/techdoc/index.html?/help/releases/R2009a/techdoc/creating_plots/bqsxy8a-1.html#brdjjbz-1), and use different portions of the concatenated map for different axes (this only works for images)
2. Use [`subimage`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/subimage.html) if you have the Image Processing Toolbox (again, only for images)
3. The [`freezeColors`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors-unfreezecolors) File Exchange submission, which can hold any plots colormap.

The basic usage of `freezeColors` is similar to `hold`. For plots on different axes:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
ezsurf('sqrt(x^2 + y^2)')
colormap(jet)
freezeColors  % submission by John Iversen

subplot(1,2,2)
contour(peaks,30)
colormap(copper)
```

For plots on the same axes:

```
surf(peaks) % jet
freezeColors
hold on
mesh(peaks')
colormap(copper)
```

Output:

[image]

**NOTE**: You have to call `freezeColors` repeatedly after each plot (`surf`, `mesh`, etc.).

**NOTE 2**: Do not use `unfreezeColors` (e.g. in a plotting loop) unless you want to revert to using the same color maps. This fixed the second question added in the edit to the question.

Comment: I edited my above question to show you what happens when I use freezeColors – maybe I'm not using it properly?

Comment: @NickSweet Hard to say without your data, but perhaps put `unfreezeColors` and `hold off` after the loop.

Comment: Got it! I didn't use unfreezeColors and that made it work! Thanks!