# subplots with different colormaps matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot, contourf

I am trying to make a graph with two different contourf subplots that use completely different colormaps. However with the code I currently have (which creates a custom colormap for one of the subplots), the subplots come out with the same colormap. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
h = figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
title('GEFS 20 Member Mean Vorticity');
axesm('eqdcylin','maplonlimit',[-180 179],'maplatlimit',[0 90]);
%eqdcylin
contourm(gLat, gLon, squeeze(meanhx(x,:,:))', 16,'Color',[0.05 0.05 0.05],'LineWidth',2);
hold on
contourfm(gLat, gLon, squeeze(vmeanx(x,:,:))', 30, 'LineStyle', 'none'); 
shading flat;
lm=worldlo('POline');
  for i=1:length(lm);
  lm(i).otherproperty = {'color','m','LineWidth',1.5};
  end
displaym(lm);
gridm on;
tightmap;
set(h, 'Position', [1 1 2200 1100]);
colormap(b2r(-5*10^-5, 5*10^-5));
freezeColors;
cbfreeze(colorbar)




%caxis([-5*10^-5 5*10^-5])

colorbar;


subplot(2,1,2)
title('GEFS 20 Member Vorticity Variance');
axesm('eqdcylin','maplonlimit',[-180 179],'maplatlimit',[0 90]);
%eqdcylin
contourm(gLat, gLon, squeeze(meanhx(x,:,:))', 16,'Color',[0.05 0.05 0.05],'LineWidth',2);
hold on
contourfm(gLat, gLon, squeeze(vvarx(x,:,:))', 30, 'LineStyle', 'none'); 
shading flat;
lm=worldlo('POline');
  for i=1:length(lm);
  lm(i).otherproperty = {'color','m','LineWidth',1.5};
  end 
displaym(lm);
gridm on;
tightmap;
set(h, 'Position', [1 1 2200 1100]);

mycmap = [
0.9961    0.9961    0.9961;
0.6641    0.6641    0.9974;
0.3320    0.3320    0.9987;
     0         0    1.0000;
     0    0.2500    1.0000;
     0    0.5000    1.0000;
     0    0.7500    1.0000;
     0    1.0000    1.0000;
0.2000    1.0000    0.8000;
0.4000    1.0000    0.6000;
0.6000    1.0000    0.4000;
0.8000    1.0000    0.2000;
1.0000    1.0000         0;
1.0000    0.9333         0;
1.0000    0.8667         0;
1.0000    0.8000         0;
1.0000    0.7333         0;
1.0000    0.6667         0;
1.0000    0.6000         0;
1.0000    0.5333         0;
1.0000    0.4667         0;
1.0000    0.4000         0;
1.0000    0.3333         0;
1.0000    0.2667         0;
1.0000    0.2000         0;
1.0000    0.1333         0;
1.0000    0.0667         0;
1.0000         0         0;
0.9854         0         0;
0.9708         0         0;
0.9561         0         0;
0.9415         0         0;
0.9269         0         0;
0.9123         0         0;
0.8977         0         0;
0.8830         0         0;
0.8684         0         0;
0.8538         0         0;
0.8392         0         0;
0.8246         0         0;
0.8099         0         0;
0.7953         0         0;
0.7807         0         0;
0.7661         0         0;
0.7515         0         0;
0.7368         0         0;
0.7222         0         0;
0.7092         0         0;
0.6961         0         0;
0.6830         0         0;
0.6699         0         0;
0.6569         0         0;
0.6438         0         0;
0.6307         0         0;
0.6176         0         0;
0.6046         0         0;
0.5915         0         0;
0.5784         0         0;
0.5654         0         0;
0.5523         0         0;
0.5392         0         0;
0.5261         0         0;
0.5131         0         0;
0.5000         0         0;
];

colormap(mycmap);






freezeColors;
cbfreeze(colorbar);


set(gcf, 'renderer', 'zbuffer');
```

Comment: not minimal nor reproducible; did you go through the examples in freezeColors?

Comment: Sure did, how can I make this minimal and reproducible.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is related to R, but equally valid for Matlab and any programming question. A google search would give you hundreds of hits.. Additionally take a look at SO's [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have repeatedly searched google, and continue to come back with the same issue as there does not seem to be a solution that directly solves this problem. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking here. Additionally, I'm not sure what exactly it is that makes this not reproducible, there is nothing here that is not reproducible, and the code is simply a cluttered (with mapping lines) contourf plot.

Comment: It is not so simple to solve, have a look here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39741044/2627163 and if you can make a sand-alone code that I can run, I will add 2 colormaps to it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: it seems, that the documentation is wrong! See comments!**

By using the second argument of the colormap function, one should be able to assign a specific colormap to a specific (sub-)plot or axes, if you want to call it like that:

Referring to [TMW: colormap](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html):

Be aware that **the first argument** is the handle to the axes!

```
colormap(ax,map)
```

> sets the colormap for the axes specified by ax. Each axes within a
>   figure can have a unique colormap. After you set an axes colormap,
>   changing the figure colormap does not affect the axes.

How to get the handle of the axes?:

when plotting with plot(x,y..) you get it as the return-value. Catch it with:

```
ax = plot(x,y..)
```

For other plot-functions, as you seem to use, you should find some info about that within the doku.

Comment: this is wrong. The question is about multiple colormaps in a subplot. The above only works when each plot is in a different figure. Even if you get the axis handle for a single subplot, setting its colormap will change the colormap of all other axis in the figure.

Comment: gosh, it seems that you are right. I just got this form the documentation. Did I got this wrong?-> "Each axes within a figure can have a unique colormap" or is there something wrong with the documentation..? :o

Comment: apparently yes. It's very easy to test, `data = randi (64, 10); hax1 = subplot (1, 2, 1); image (data); colormap (hax1, jet); hax2 = subplot (1, 2, 2); image (data); colormap (hax2, hot);` Mathwork's solution for this is an [absolute joke](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101346-how-do-i-use-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure). You must create a colormap that is the concatenation of each subplot colormap and adjust the values on each accordingly. And if you want colorbars, you need to set their ranges manually too.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to MATLAB 2017a, you can assign a colormap to each axes object using the syntax `colormap(axesHandle, cMap)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image Processing toolbox, you can use the function [`subimage`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/subimage.html) to display images with their respective colormaps:

```
X1=imread('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Burosch_Blue-Only_Test_pattern.jpg');
X2=imread('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Romsey_River_Test.jpg');
subplot(1,2,1), subimage(X1)
subplot(1,2,2), subimage(X2)
```

Result:

[image: two images in one figure]

**Edit** there is a more complete answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22647274/2777181).

Comment: I'm not loading in images though, I'm calculating contourf plots. Would this work similarly?

Comment: @agold2121 I just realized it only works for images (i.e matrices), check the link for ways to do it with plots.

Comment: @agold2121 `freezeColors` is not solving your issue?

Comment: No, its actually freezing the same colors to both subplots.